# How to compare string type columns character by character without looping?

Tags: sql, sql-server, comparison

I have two columns: One column holds actual answers, the other one is the answer_key.

I want to compare answers to answer_key and have scores in the third column:

```
 ID   Answers    Answer_key    Score
  1   ABCD        ABCC          1110  
  2   ACD         DCA            010
```

Of course, I can check the length, loop through each character to compare them individually, and get the score.

However, is there an alternative? Possibly based on XML path?

Comment: I suspect your design is far from optimal. Normalise...

Comment: As you mention checking the length: Could it be different? If so: What should the outcome of the comparison be? What is the range of possible individual values A…D?

Comment: @Abecee as you can see in my example. There are 2 different records with different length. So I need to check the length for looping.

Comment: OK - so within the row, one is safe assuming equal length No need to compensate for an answer not given…

Comment: The possible answer values range from A through D - no further?

Comment: @Abecee No need to compare for blank Answers. Answer values are not fixed can be A through F Sometimes Numbers.

Comment: Sorry - would need to know all possible values. So, which numbers, please?

Comment: @Abecee Values A through F and 1 to 3

Answer (score 0):

You might try binary values rather than letters.

```
A=0001  B=0010 C=0100 D=1000
ABCD = 0001001001001000  (0x1248)
ABCC = 0001001001000100  (0x1244)

Score = (Answers XOR Answer_key) XOR 11111111
```

The XOR 11111111 is optional

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to split each char in `Answers` and `Answers_Key` into separate rows and then compare them. This can be done using a `Recursive CTE`. The concatenation is done using the `FOR XML PATH` function.

```
CREATE TABLE temp(
    Answers     VARCHAR(10),
    Answer_Key  VARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('ABCD', 'ABCC'), ('ACD', 'DCA');

;WITH temp_numbered AS(
    SELECT 
        ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Answer_Key), 
        * 
    FROM temp
),
cte AS(
    SELECT
        ID,
        Answer_Key_Char =   SUBSTRING(Answer_Key, 1, 1),
        Answer_Key      =   STUFF(Answer_Key, 1, 1, ''),
        Answers_Char    =   SUBSTRING(Answers, 1, 1),
        Answers         =   STUFF(Answers, 1, 1, ''),
        RowID           =   1
    FROM temp_numbered t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        ID,
        Answer_Key_Char =   SUBSTRING(Answer_Key, 1, 1),
        Answers         =   STUFF(Answer_Key, 1, 1, ''),
        Answers_Char    =   SUBSTRING(Answers, 1, 1),
        Answers         =   STUFF(Answers, 1, 1, ''),
        RowID           =   RowID + 1
    FROM cte
    WHERE LEN(Answer_Key) > 0
)
SELECT 
    Answers,
    Answer_Key,
    Score = (SELECT 
                CASE WHEN Answer_Key_Char = Answers_Char THEN '1' ELSE '0' END
            FROM cte
            WHERE ID = t.ID
            ORDER BY ID, RowID
            FOR XML PATH(''))
FROM temp_numbered t

DROP TABLE temp
```

Here is another way using a `Tally Table`:

```
;WITH tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP 11000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM sys.columns
)
,temp_numbered AS(
    SELECT 
        ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Answer_Key), 
        * 
    FROM temp
)
,cte AS(
    SELECT
        ID,
        Answer_Key_Char =   SUBSTRING(Answer_Key, N, 1),
        Answers_Char    =   SUBSTRING(Answers, N, 1),
        RowID           =   N
    FROM temp_numbered tn
    CROSS JOIN Tally t
    WHERE t.N <= LEN(tn.Answer_Key)
)
SELECT 
    Answers,
    Answer_Key,
    Score = (SELECT 
                CASE WHEN Answer_Key_Char = Answers_Char THEN '1' ELSE '0' END
            FROM cte
            WHERE ID = t.ID
            ORDER BY ID, RowID
            FOR XML PATH(''))
FROM temp_numbered t
```

Comment: That solution is really great but have question recurssion is limite to 100 so if I have along answer_key string more than 100 charcaters then?

Answer (score 0):

I seems easiest to loop through each character for the whole set at once:

```
-- get max Answer length
declare @len int,@max_len int
select @max_len = max(len(Answers)),
  @len = 1
from Answers

-- update scores
while @len <= @max_len
  begin
    update Answers
      set Score = isnull(Score,'') + '1'
      where substring(Answers,@len,1) = substring(Answer_Key,@len,1)
        and len(Answers) >= @len
    update Answers
      set Score = isnull(Score,'') + '0'
      where substring(Answers,@len,1) != substring(Answer_Key,@len,1)
        and len(Answers) >= @len
    set @len = @len + 1
  end

-- return Scores
select * from Answers
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b08e9/5)**

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer from @weswesthemenace to get around cte limit.

```
DECLARE @Answers TABLE
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) not null,
    Answers VARCHAR(MAX) not null,
    Answer_Key VARCHAR(MAX) not null
)

INSERT INTO @Answers (Answers, Answer_Key) VALUES ('ABCD', 'ABCC')
INSERT INTO @Answers (Answers, Answer_Key) VALUES ('ACD', 'DCA')
INSERT INTO @Answers (Answers, Answer_Key) VALUES ('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEGGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXXYZABCDEFGHIIKKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZZ');

WITH
  E01(N) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
  E02(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E01 a CROSS JOIN E01 b),
  E04(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E02 a CROSS JOIN E02 b),
  E08(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E04 a CROSS JOIN E04 b),
  E16(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E08 a CROSS JOIN E08 b),
  E32(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E16 a CROSS JOIN E16 b),
  cteTally(N) AS (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY N) FROM E32)

SELECT b.Answers, b.Answer_Key, 
    (
      SELECT CASE when SUBSTRING(a.Answer_Key, n.N, 1) = SUBSTRING(a.Answers, n.N, 1) then '1' else '0' end
        FROM @Answers a
          CROSS APPLY cteTally n
        WHERE b.Id = a.Id AND n.N <= DATALENGTH(b.Answers)
        ORDER BY ID, n.N
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) Score
  FROM @Answers b
```

this can be simplified by a utility Number function in the database. Mine is called dbo.Number(start, end)

```
SELECT b.Answers, b.Answer_Key, 
    (
      SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(a.Answer_Key, n.N, 1) = SUBSTRING(a.Answers, n.N, 1) THEN '1' ELSE '0' END
        FROM @Answers a
          CROSS APPLY dbo.Number(1, DATALENGTH(b.Answers)) n
        WHERE b.Id = a.Id
        ORDER BY ID, n.N
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) Score
  FROM @Answers b
```